# Use Python to make HTTP Post Request for form

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, http, post

I am trying to make an HTTP Post request using Python. The specific form I want to submit is on the following page: http://143.137.111.105/Enlace/Resultados2010/Basica2010/R10Folio.aspx

Using Chrome Dev Tools it seems like pushing the button makes an HTTP Post request but I am trying to figure out the exact request that is made. I currently have the following in Python:

```
import requests
url = 'http://143.137.111.105/Enlace/Resultados2010/Basica2010/R10Folio.aspx'
values = {
    'txtFolioAlumno': '210227489P10',
}

r = requests.post(url, values)
print r.content
```

However, when I run this it simply prints out the HTML of the old page instead of returning the data from the new page (I am interested in getting the number next to 'Matematicas', 422 in this case). I have achieved this task using Selenium which actually opens a test browser, but I want to query the server directly.

Comment: You can post only if only there exists a page end point which accepts a post request. But in your case, it is a asp.net website page, not a web service, which does not accept post like what you did.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Is there any way to programmatically achieve the effect of clicking the button and accessing the information on the next page without having to use something like Selenium?